# Rented movie disappeared from iTunes

Tags: itunes

So, I rented guardians of the galaxy to watch on a plane ride, I downloaded it the night before I left so it would have enough time to download, I checked right before I left and it was fully downloaded, then when I went on the plane and no longer had internet connection the movie was no longer in my movies or in my unwatched movies.I never started playing the movie so I should have had 30 days. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to launch iTunes and from the menu bar select
 Store -> Check Available Downloads

If that does not work, just contact Apple Support. Reference your order number, and they should push the download back down to you.

They do have a 24 hour turn around on this, so do it earlier rather than later so you'll have it for your next flight!

http://www.apple.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Store -> Account -> At the top it will say something about available downloads and if you want to download now. Click the download now button and you should be good to go.

Comment: "**_I downloaded it the night before I left so it would have enough time to download_**"